# What does this C++ code mean? 'const ResTable& res = am->getResources();'

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to understand how R file is read in android, everything went well before I see this line:

```
const ResTable& res = am->getResources();
```

I found this line at file

core/jni/android/android_util_AssetManager.cpp

in method

```
static jobject android_content_AssetManager_getAssignedPackageIdentifiers(JNIEnv* env, jobject clazz)
```

I have learned some c&cpp before, but have never seen syntax like this, what does this mean? I found ResTable is a class, but I can't find symbol 'res' anywhere. Is this file I'm reading broken or I'm I missing something?

thanks for any help!

Comment: `res` is a new reference to a constant `ResTable` that is returned from the method `am->getResources()` .  If this is still a problem try an introduction to C++ book.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/596750/2491746

Comment: Oh now I recall it, reference... I have never used it even I have learned about it, almost forgot reference. Thanks a lot! Now I can go on reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It calls the `getResources` method for the `AssetManager` instance pointed to by `am` and saves the result in `res`. The type of `res` is `const ResTable&`, i.e. a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) to a `const ResTable` (which also is the return type of [`AssetManager::getResources`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/gingerbread/libs/utils/AssetManager.cpp#500)).